# Remove extra space in mixed script

Tags: spacing, xetex, polyglossia, bidi

I needed to write '‫שלום!‬' but without a space between the 'ם' and the '!'.

The document is mainly in english with just a few Hebrew words in it.

A minimal example of what I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
\noindent
!\texthebrew{שלום} \\
!hello \\
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

It currently looks like:

[image]

With what looks like an extra space between the exclamation mark and the nearest letter.

Edit: include missing usepackage

Edit2:

The output after adding `\listfiles` is:

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
FiraSans.sty    2019/10/10 (Bob Tennent and autoinst) Style file for Fira Sans
fonts.
 ifxetex.sty    2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
fontspec.sty    2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2020-10-05 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2020-10-05 L3 programming layer (loader)
l3backend-xetex.def    2020-09-24 L3 backend support: XeTeX
xparse-generic.tex
fontspec-xetex.sty    2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
fontspec.cfg
polyglossia.sty    2020/10/15 v1.50a Modern multilingual typesetting with XeLaT
eX and LuaLaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
l3keys2e.sty    2020-10-05 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
filehook.sty    2020/09/29 v0.8a Hooks for input files
filehook-2020.sty    2020/09/29 v0.8a Hooks for input files
gloss-latex.ldf    polyglossia: module for default language
gloss-english.ldf    polyglossia: module for english
gloss-hebrew.ldf    polyglossia: module for hebrew
    bidi.sty    2020/05/17 v36.3 Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and LaT
eX
biditools.sty    2020/05/13 v2 Programming tools for bidi package
zref-abspage.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi package
with kernel methods
latex-xetex-bidi.def    2019/03/03 v1.3.7 bidi adaptations for `latex.ltx' for
XeTeX engine
footnote-xetex-bidi.def    2017/08/09 v1.1 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX engin
e
report-xetex-bidi.def    2017/06/09 v0.8 bidi adaptations for standard report c
lass for XeTeX engine
loadingorder-xetex-bidi.def    2017/12/29 v0.97 making sure that bidi is the la
st package loaded
hebrewcal.sty    2019/12/03 v2.7 Hebrew calendar for polyglossia (adapted from
hebcal.sty in Babel)
cal-util.def
babel-hebrewalph.def    2010/03/02 Babel definitions for Hebrew numerals
 Adapted from hebrew.ldf (2005/03/30 v2.3h)
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

Edit 3: font  used in output pdf:

[image]

Comment: I guess you should update your TeX system.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `sf` from `\hebrewfontsf`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    !\texthebrew{שלום} \\
    !hello \\
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Edit:**

With `\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}`, I cannot reproduce the error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    !\texthebrew{שלום} \\
    !hello \\
\end{document}
```

[image: second try]

**Edit 2:** Output of `\listfiles`

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
FiraSans.sty    2019/10/10 (Bob Tennent and autoinst) Style file for Fira Sans 
fonts.
 ifxetex.sty    2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
fontspec.sty    2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2021-11-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2021-11-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-xetex.def    2021-12-14 L3 backend support: XeTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
fontspec.cfg
polyglossia.sty    2021/04/12 v1.53 Modern multilingual typesetting with XeLaTe
X and LuaLaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
l3keys2e.sty    2021-11-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
gloss-latex.ldf    polyglossia: module for default language
gloss-english.ldf    polyglossia: module for english
gloss-hebrew.ldf    polyglossia: module for hebrew
    bidi.sty    2020/05/17 v36.3 Bidirectional typesetting in plain TeX and LaT
eX
biditools.sty    2020/05/13 v2 Programming tools for bidi package
zref-abspage.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
latex-xetex-bidi.def    2019/03/03 v1.3.7 bidi adaptations for `latex.ltx' for 
XeTeX engine
footnote-xetex-bidi.def    2017/08/09 v1.1 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX engin
e
report-xetex-bidi.def    2017/06/09 v0.8 bidi adaptations for standard report c
lass for XeTeX engine
loadingorder-xetex-bidi.def    2017/12/29 v0.97 making sure that bidi is the la
st package loaded
hebrewcal.sty    2019/12/03 v2.7 Hebrew calendar for polyglossia (adapted from 
hebcal.sty in Babel)
cal-util.def
babel-hebrewalph.def    2010/03/02 Babel definitions for Hebrew numerals
 Adapted from hebrew.ldf (2005/03/30 v2.3h)
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

**Edit 3:** Screenshots of fonts

[image: fonts]

Comment: Couldn't make it work by removing the 'sf'. The shape (or rather width of the lines) of the letters changed but the space still remains. Or is this just for me?

Comment: Are you using the exact MWE? Because your initial MWE wasn't even compilable for me and the font in `!hello` is not the default font.

Comment: Sorry i had missed a `\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}`. Could that be responsible for the difference? Sorry again for having a non-working MCVE. I have edited the question.

Comment: See my edit. There must be something else wrong in your example.

Comment: Strange.. That's exactly how my code looks like. I suppose the distribution doesn't make any difference, but I'm using texlive,

Comment: I tried copy posting the code from your edited answer too. It gives the same output with the extra space.

Comment: @J...S add `\listfiles` to your preamble then show the resulting list in your question, people can then compare versions

Comment: It looks like you have a different hebrew font installed, look at the last character

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've edited the question with the output of `\listfiles`. Can it shed any light on the issue?

Comment: @marv I'm using an older texlive (2020), versions of some packages in our `\listfiles` output differ only in the year. Maybe that matters?

Comment: `diff j-s marv` output of `\listfiles`: https://bpa.st/BAPA

Comment: @J...S don't know, maybe update texlive version. I have also added a screenshot of the embedded fonts. (you can see them with Acrobat Reader under Properties>Fonts)

Comment: Had been reluctant to update as that would mean a complete [reinstall](https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html) (for inexperienced users).

Comment: @J...S i don't think that the texlive version is the issue. Compare our outputs, we use a different font. I donwloaded mine [here](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Hebrew).

Comment: I couldn't figure out from the `\listfiles` outputs how the fonts were different. How can we identify it?

Comment: Look at the last character of the output. Your one has a sharp edge lower left, while mine is round.

Comment: Ah.. in the output pdf themselves. Yeah.. I get it now.

Comment: Maybe your font file is somehow corrupt, you could consider removing it and reinstall the font from the link i provided

Comment: Wouldn't the font files being used show up when using `\listfiles`?

Comment: Been trying to understand from where I installed the noto fonts and just realized that it's probably from the OS's package manager (fonts-noto package in ubuntu)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133282/discussion-between-marv-and-j-s).